# duplicate file exists,while on updation shows on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: apt, updates

updation error continuously shows , after sudo apt-get update, after hit 56, stooped and error shows like 'duplicate file exists and 'sudo apt-get update' to correct these problem !
but after doing this many time I'm getting same result , please help me!

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: name@nameLenovo-G470:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for name: 
..Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

done apt-get update again, but same output result ! what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: same result , no working !!

Comment: copy and paste the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` command in pastebin.com and provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VW5W48Tw

Comment: delete line no 52 from the sources.list file and then save it.